# Need Image inside container to span full width of page and still act as a inline-block / block element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have an image take the full width of the page while inside a div with a given width. I managed to do this by adding it as a background image and adding the following styles:

```
background-image: url(URL);
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
```

However, the image is on top of all my other elements now, so I need to have the div display as a block or inline block element, but I'm not really sure the route to make this happen since when I apply those as styles nothing changes. Let me know if there is a good way to do what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Here is a JSFiddle example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/T2t47/13/

Comment: Jsfiddle,net example with HTML/CSS and actual image please.

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T2t47/

Comment: Try removing your position absolute...

Comment: That works, but on my live site The div containing it has a fixed width, the updated JSFiddle shows this: http://jsfiddle.net/T2t47/13/

Comment: @BillyJ Will post answer in a min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason your elements are falling beneath this element is because it taken out of the document flow. (As you may have read earlier.)  Think of this as a box surrounded by pebbles.  With the box in place, the pebbles sit finely around the box.  However if we pull the box up, some of our pebbles fall beneath the box, and we can no longer see them.  It's counted as what I like to call, a ghost element.  It's undetected and untouchable by other elements.

(Sorry I know this is getting pretty winded.)

Essentially, what you're doing in your project is breaking it.  If an element is 200 pixels wide, nothing inside of it should be more than 200 pixels wide.

Therefore the best workaround, i've provided in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2t47/36/) shows you to set the parent element to no max-width.  But to add container elements, inside of this container element wrapping the necessary elements, and to set their widths to whatever set width you need to.

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
}
.h1-container{
  width: 200px
}
.img-container{
  width: 100%;
}
```

This allows the image element room to breath, and other elements the containment they need.

Also, an excellent link on positions: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioning-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Thank you! The problem seemed to come from not having my container's height set, so things were thinking it was 0. I also think that Liam's solution with using after is necessary too though, so I combined the results.

Comment: Agreed, Liam seems to know how to use positions well.  Position absolute will sets the elements position on the page based on the entire browser.  Whereas relative sets it based on the elements around it.  Read up on them because they used to fool me too!

Answer (score 2):

Look like this might be what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/T2t47/12/

```
.introduction div {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size:cover;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    z-index: -999;
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but I forgot to include the restraint on .introduction of a fixed width which is shown in my updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/T2t47/13/. Your example is what I would like it to look like though

Comment: infact, this solution allows you to eliminate the image div altogether... http://jsfiddle.net/T2t47/35/

Comment: This looks great! I'm going to try applying this to the site now and will see how it goes.

Comment: If it goes well, I'll update the main answer above with the full solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want the image to appear above the list in your example? If so, simply removing position: absolute; and left: 0; should keep the image filling the full width of the page and place it above the list. This is because position: absolute; takes the div out of the document flow.

So your style will be:

```
.introduction div {
    background-position: 0 -99px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/94Yvw/

Comment: This works, but on my live site The div containing it has a fixed width, the updated JSFiddle shows this: http://jsfiddle.net/T2t47/13/

Comment: Set the width to a higher width, and any elements inside of the document that need to be smaller can be set within a seperate container.

Comment: Andrew's suggestion would fix the issue, is there any reason why the containing div has a fixed width?

Answer (score 1):

it can be easily done with `vw` units and negative margin. And it's responsive friendly.

```
.full-width-block {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;  
  margin-left: -50vw;
}
```

See my fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ondrejruzicka/ghs6kmgw/

Answer (score 0):

Is this your desired result?

```
.introduction div {
    background-position: 0 -99px;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 500px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -5; /* now it is not on top of everything ! */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T2t47/4/

Comment: No, I want it to push the list down the page and act like a normal div. Thank you though :)

Comment: [Click me](http://jsfiddle.net/T2t47/9/) :

Ok, in this case all you need to change is the position to relative. Absolutely positioned elements are placed regarding the document, they don't "care" about other elements. The z-index  is used to make the absolutely positioned elements act as layers. If no z-index is specified, the image will just sit on top of everything.